# Scotch box - npm install error

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, package.json

I started to use Scotch Box (Vagrant LAMP stack) for the first time, I used to install my dev dependencies via my personal *package.json*.

```
{
"name": "myApp",
"dependencies": {},
"devDependencies": {
"gulp": "*",
"gulp-util": "*",
"gulp-plumber": "*",
"gulp-coffee": "*",
"gulp-concat": "*",
"gulp-uglify": "*",
"gulp-imagemin": "*",
"gulp-compass": "*",
"gulp-minify-html": "*",
"gulp-minify-css": "*",
"gulp-useref": "*",
"del": "*",
"require-dir": "*"
}
}
```

But when I run *npm install* I see many errors like:

- npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
- npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-23-generic
- npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"

Adding sudo does not change anything. Do you have any idea? I just want to have my "personal" *node_modules* for each project I make.

Comment: I found a workaround to my issue:
After trying solutions posted by others users like *npm install --no-bin-links* or *npm install -g* or running those commands as root, I decided to move my *package.json* to */home/vagrant/*. From there I can run *sudo npm install*, all my packages have been downloaded successfully. To finish, I have created a symbolic link from my project (*/var/www/public/my-project*) to the *node_modules* directory located in my home.

Comment: I tried to follow this Ticket on VirtualBox website about Windows symbolic link creation but it did not work... https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085